# Need drivers for raspberry pi TL-WN725n v3 for raspbian version 4.14.98+ #1200

Tags: raspbian, usb, wireless-adapter, pi-b+

The problem is I am not finding drivers for tp-link TL-WN725N version 3 
my raspbian version is 4.4.98+ with a build #1200
Can anyone please help me with this?
I am stuck with this from 2days.

Comment: What kind of drivers do you need?

Comment: usb wireless adapters